# Scripting a simple counter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wanted to create a simple script, which counts values in one column, that are higher in another column:

```py
d = {'a': [1, 3], 'b': [0, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=[1, 2])

print(df)
```

```py
   a  b
1  1  0
2  3  2
```

My function:

```py
def diff(dataframe):
    a_counter=0
    b_counter=0
    
    for i in dataframe["a"]:
        for ii in dataframe["b"]:
            if i>ii:
                a_counter+=1
            elif ii>i:
                b_counter+=1

    return a_counter, b_counter
```

However

```py
diff(df)
```

returns (3, 1), instead of (2,0). I know the problem is that every single value of one column gets compared to every value of the other column (e.g. 1 gets compared to 0 and 2 of column b). There probably is a special function for my problem, but can you help me fix my script?

Comment: do you mean `df['a'].ge(df['b']).value_counts()`?

Comment: and to *fix* your script: `for i, ii in zip(df[a'], df['b']):` instead of the two `for` loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest adding some helper columns in an intuitive way to help compute the sum of each condition `a > b` and `b > a`

A working example based on your code :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = {'a': [1, 3], 'b': [0, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=[1, 2])

def diff(dataframe):
    dataframe['a>b'] = np.where(dataframe['a']>dataframe['b'], 1, 0)
    dataframe['b>a'] = np.where(dataframe['b']>dataframe['a'], 1, 0)
    return dataframe['a>b'].sum(), dataframe['b>a'].sum()

print(diff(df))

>>> (2, 0)
```

Basically what `np.where()` does, the way I used it, is that it produces `1`  if the condition is met and `0` otherwise. You can then add those columns up using a simple `sum()` function applied on the desired columns.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Maybe you can use:

```
>>> df['a'].gt(df['b']).sum(), df['b'].gt(df['a']).sum()
(2, 0)
```

IIUC, to fix your code:

```
def diff(dataframe):
    a_counter=0
    b_counter=0
    
    for i in dataframe["a"]:
        for ii in dataframe["b"]:
            if i>ii:
                a_counter+=1
            elif ii>i:
                b_counter+=1

    # Subtract the minimum of counters
    m = min(a_counter, b_counter)   
    return a_counter-m, b_counter-m
```

Output:

```
>>> diff(df)
(2, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use the sign of the difference and count the values:

```
d = {1: 'a', -1: 'b', 0: 'equal'}

(np.sign(df['a'].sub(df['b']))
   .map(d)
   .value_counts()
   .reindex(list(d.values()), fill_value=0)
)
```

output:

```
a        2
b        0
equal    0
dtype: int64
```